# How to add column name from the pd.concat?

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering is there any way to add column name from **series** of data.

I thought is something like this

`std_df = pd.concat([q,w], axis=1, columns= ["apple","banana"])`

But I get an error of `concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'`

I've tried **names** instead of **columns**, still not working.

Comment: try using `names` arg... read it here: `https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html`

Comment: @ManojKumar I've tried it, but still not working. I don't know why

Comment: But I will add in to my question

Comment: please provide some data of two dataframes also to help us better understand the requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pd.concat()` has the `keys` parameter that will work for this purpose:

```
s1 = pd.Series([1,2,3])
s2 = pd.Series([4,5,6])

df = pd.concat([s1,s2],keys = ['A','B'],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Comment: Oh!!! This one is doing in more efficient way!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to set the axis labels?

```
pd.concat([pd.Series([1,2]),pd.Series([3,4])],axis=1).set_axis(labels=['A','B'],axis=1)
```

Output

```
   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

Comment: Per the docs, the names parameter is only for naming levels in a multiindex - the docs show a pretty clear example of when that would be applied.

Comment: Oh, okay, I think I miss it:)

Answer (score 0):

I believe pd.concat() has no parameter columns. You should delete that.

```
std_df = pd.concat([q,w], axis=1)
```

Comment: Yes I know, that is what I **thought**. I know it's incorrect

Comment: Sorry for the reply. I didn't get you I question. Now I think I understand what you asked.

Comment: That's fine! Thanks for telling me!!!